# Synaptics touchpad: switch double and triple tap

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I'm running Windows 7 on an Asus U36SG laptop, with Synaptics touchpad drivers installed (the one you retrieve on the Asus support page of the laptop).

I couldn't find the option to configure double and triple tap actions, and currently I have those exactly inverted compared to the way I'm used to: the triple tap opens the cascade context menus, while the triple one opens links in new tabs in internet browsers, for example. Long story short, double tapping works as a middle mouse button, while the double one works as a right click. Can I easily get it to work the other way?

Comment: Try this: type `mouse` after pressing Win key, then select result `mouse`, now in the new windows that pops up go to a tab named `Device Settings` there you will find settings to change such behaviour.

Comment: There, I'm redirected into Synaptics control panel, which does not allow me to manually decide double and triple tap's actions...